# Different SQL Execution Plans based on WHERE value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

I have a slightly complicated SQL view that performs differently based on the value passed to a WHERE clause, and I can't explain why.

When I query the view, I have a WHERE clause that can be one of two values.  Depending on which value is used, the query returns at different speeds.

```
WHERE [Work Center] LIKE '2MSTMP' (returns 84 records in 2 seconds)
```

or

```
WHERE [Work Center] =  '2ZLSR' (returns 504 records in 15 seconds)
```

While the number of records returned is a little different, I can't believe that is causing this much of a slowdown.  When I checked the execution plan, it showed that depending on which value I passed it used a different index.  The faster query used the Clustered index, while the slower query used a NonClustered index.  See the below images for examples of what I mean.

[image: Slow]

[image: Fast]

The field that is being used in the WHERE clause is defined as varchar(8).  As a test, I converted both values to that datatype in the WHERE clause (in case it was inferring something), but that had no effect.

Can anyone give me ideas about how to research this further?  I really would like both queries to perform at the same (faster) speed, but I don't know what else to check.

Thank you!

Comment: You will need to post more of the query. Those values indicate statements from another part of the query and they don't seem to be related. Perhaps the value '2ZLSR'  indirectly forces a larger table to be joined, wheras '2MSTMP', bypasses that part?

Comment: Screenshots say you are using other columns in WHERE clause, columns like [Qty_To_Mfg] and [Status_Flag]

Answer (score 0):

What you posted is not enough to provide a great answer but here are the obvious problems I observed from the screen shot.

The slow query is reading 1,226,605 rows; the slow query is only reading 170 rows.

The predicate for the first query is:

```
WHERE STATUS_FLAG = 'A' OR STATUS_FLAG = 'R'
```

The predicate for the second one is:

```
WHERE Qty_to_mfg > 0 AND (STATUS_FLAG = 'A' OR STATUS_FLAG = 'R')
```

Perhaps adding this ^^ `WHERE Qty_to_mfg > 0` to the slower query will help.

Also note that `WHERE [Work Center] LIKE '2MSTMP'` is the same as `WHERE [Work Center] = '2MSTMP'`

Lastly - In each case, your cardinality estimates are way off in both queries. This is a sign of bad stats, wrong datatypes used in your joins/filters, or parameter sniffing. Consider checking your stats and consider running these with OPTION (RECOMPILE) to see if the recompile improves things (this is not a permanent solution but will aid in troubleshooting).

Comment: Alan - Thanks for your quick reply.  As you said, I really didn't post everything (due to the complexity), which is going to make it hard for others to see the whole picture.  I can't add the "WHERE Qty_to_mfg > 0" because that is contained in a view being queried by this main view.  Therefore, BOTH queries should use the same sub-view and get the same predicate. I have a maintenance job that updates statistics, and it seems to be executing properly, so I am not sure how to improve that. I will look at the wrong datatypes possibilities you listed and see if I can improve things there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two queries hitting the same subquery with the same predicate do not have to use the same execution plan.  The engine behind the database is designed to change its method of getting the data based on the statistics it has been given on the tables.  How you are using a view absolutely impacts the performance of a query you can't leave that out because if you are using a where clause on a value you pulled from inside your view which is basically a subquery that could be where you are having trouble getting it to understand which index to hit or maybe you got a little trigger happy with included columns on the Qty + Statflag index.  There is a stability issue with the queries ability to reuse the same execution plan the changed where clause is a red herring modifying that just made it try to pull a new plan and failed.

If [work center] is like a primary key or other searchable column buried inside the view and that is your main seek predicate you desire it is better to put that table outside the view and put your where clause on that table in the main body of the query and then inner join that to the view.